# How to serve websocket with go-swagger?

Tags: go, gorilla, go-swagger

I'm trying to serve a chat websocket within my go-swagger API. I'm using this example: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat

I tried attaching it to the http when the server starts, but after further reading I see that this can't work:

```golang
func configureServer(s *http.Server, scheme, addr string) {
  hub := chat.NewHub()

  go hub.Run()
  http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    chat.ServeWs(hub, w, r)
  })
}
```

Then I tried using a custom server and changing server.Serve() to:

```golang
hub := chat.NewHub()
go hub.Run()

http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  chat.ServeWs(hub, w, r)
})

if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", api.Serve(nil)); err != nil {
  log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

But also realized why this won't work.

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

After some reading I'm starting to understand why the /ws was never found:

```golang
hub := chat.NewHub()
go hub.Run()

mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  chat.ServeWs(hub, w, r)
})

server.SetHandler(mux)
if err := server.Serve(); err != nil {
  log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

Now the websockets works but the rest api doesn't, I can see why but I don't how to make both of them work.
I'm fairly new to golang so i'm struggling with this.

How could I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

casualjim helped me at Github:

You can put it in a middleware and hook it up in configure_XXX

```
func mountWebSockets(next http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
   return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       if r.URL.Path == "/ws" {
            chat.ServeWs(hub, w, r)
           return
       }
       next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
   }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues/2083#issuecomment-542764897